# Using NetBeans but unable to open a bat file

Tags: java, batch-file

Hello i am trying to open a bat file using java but unable...I have use this code

```
try {
   // TODO add your handling code here:
   Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:/Users/user/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Dissertation/biodwh/startBioDWH.bat");
} catch (IOException ex) {
   Logger.getLogger(AdminMenu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

please help. cmd opens but generate a message like this
could not find or load the main class launch.launcher

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:/Users/user/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Dissertation/biodwh/startBioDWH.bat");
```

By

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/Users/user/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Dissertation/biodwh/startBioDWH.bat");
```

We open the file as, but I am not sure that this will help to open bat files

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + yourfilepath);
```

Comment: No this time nothing is opened

Comment: The same error messsage could not find or load the main class launch.launcher